# Deployment Issues due to External Library

Tags: c#, deployment

I am developing a software using C# VS2019 .NET 4.7 and an external library, the library (dll) was built using C++, therefore, the libraries were accessed using the wrappers.

The issues is that the software runs perfectly well under debug and release modes. When software is installed, it gives `type initialization` error.

What is strange is that the deployed software runs perfectly well on another testing machine with the same configuration when installed.

Both the Code and the Wrappers were built using the Solution platform "Any CPU". Every detail is taken care including the conversion UTF string to ASCII string. I do not understand what is the issue with the developer machine as to why it runs under debug and release mode but not when installed on the developer machine but runs successfully in test machines.

Of course there is static class initialization in the wrapper, which is definitely not the source of the issue.

Both developer and test machines run in Windows 64 bit OS and have x64 based processors.

Anybody has any idea what went wrong here.

Comment: Firstly, paste the exact exception, Secondly, Native DLLs have a *bitness* and are built for either 32bit or 64bit architecture. Though on saying that you would tend to get a different error if bitness was an issue

Comment: Type initialization exception often throw from static constructror and static fields when launching the app. Check stack trace.

Comment: @MichaelRandall the DLLs were built for 64bit architecture that should not be an issue. Again, it was clearly evident that the product was running successfully on test machine which has the same configuration as the developer machine. This I am unable to understand.